# How to correctly redirect/submit POST request from a form (wtforms) to a REST api (flask-restless)?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-restless

I can't find a proper way to redirect data from submitted form to a REST api.

Currently - like in example below - "POST" method is handled in the view/route (see route "add_person()").

My sample data model (SQLAlchemy-based):

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

Form for rendering via html (wtforms-based):

```
class PersonForm(FlaskForm):
    name = TextField("Person name", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

View/route declaration:

```
@views.route('add_person', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_person():
    form = PersonForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        person = Person()
        person.name = form.name.data
        db.session.add(person)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('view.add_person'))
    return render_template('person_add.html', form=form)
```

HTML template:

```
<form method="POST" action="/add_person">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now I'd like to delegate database/CRUD related actions to a REST api.

API endpoint generated for a "Person" data model is: "**/api/person**".

If I switch form's "action" from:

```
"/add_person"
```

to:

```
"/api/person",
```

then I'm redirected to the API url, so I guess that's not a proper way of doing that.

I think I still should be using the view/route handling and make a POST api call there instead of persisting the "Person" object. Is this the cleanest solution? How could I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this myself. 
I ended up with staying with form's "/add_person" POST action that's handled in Flask, and then making request to API endpoint using Python "requests" library.